# Combining unrelated Models in Formset and saving results

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

These are the models related to my problem:

```
Models.py

class SequenceDiagram(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    attributeMappingName = models.TextField(blank=True)

class AttributeFilter(models.Model):
    seqDiagram = models.ForeignKey(SequenceDiagram)
    attributeName = models.TextField(blank=True)
    protocol = models.TextField()
    isDisplayed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class AttributeMapping(models.Model):
    mappingName = models.TextField()
    protocol = models.TextField(blank=True)
    nativeName = models.TextField(blank=True)
    customName = models.TextField(blank=True
```

Filters are specific to each SequenceDiagram but mappings are generic and applicable to different Diagrams.

I want a Formset with all AttributeFilters and AttributeMappings linked with the SequenceDiagram.

These are to be displayed in a table where isDisplayed and customName can be edited and then saved to the database.

> How can I combine them to a Formset and then save the users changes?

Can a many-to-many relationship help solve my problem? If so, in which end should it be defined?

Please tell me if anything needs to be clarified.

**edit**

The resulting table should look like this:

```
Protocol|Native|Custom|Display
 prot1  | Nat1 | Cus1 | Chkbx1
 prot2  | Nat2 | Cus2 | Chkbx2
 .......
```

So that matching customNames and isDisplayed are aligned.

I have tried using `objects.extra()` but I can't seem to save the changes to the 'other' model, I also don't know how to get the queryset to a Formfield and back.

`AttributeFilter.objects.extra(
 select={"protocol":"protocol", "sd":"sdAttributeName"}, 
 where=["customName=nativeName"],
 tables=["project_attributemapping"])`

Answer (score 0):

You can display both forms in the template and the process the forms separately in the view.

Here, we will be using `ModelForms`. We will create `ModelForm` for each model and then save all the models in a single view.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 
from my_app.models import SequenceDiagram, AttributeFilter, AttributeMapping

class SequenceDiagramForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SequenceDiagram

class AttributeFilterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AttributeFilter
        exclude = (seqDiagram,)

class AttributeMappingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AttributeMapping
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import View

class MyView(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sequence_diagram_form = SequenceDiagramForm(request.POST) # create form instance and populate with data
        attribute_filter_form = AttributeFilterForm(request.POST) # create form instance and populate with data
        attribute_mapping_form = AttributeMappingForm(request.POST) # create form instance and populate with data

        sequence_diagram_form_valid = sequence_diagram_form.is_valid() # check if 'SequenceDiagramForm' is valid
        attribute_filter_form_valid = attribute_filter_form.is_valid() # check if 'AttributeFilterForm' is valid
        attribute_mapping_form_valid = attribute_mapping_form.is_valid() # check if 'AttributeMappingForm' is valid

        # Check if all the forms are valid
        if sequence_diagram_form_valid and attribute_filter_form_valid and attribute_mapping_form_valid:
            sequence_diagram_obj = sequence_diagram_form.save() # save the SequenceDiagram object
            attribute_filter_obj = attribute_filter_form.save(commit=False) # not save but get the instance 
            attribute_mapping_obj = attribute_mapping_form.save() # save the AttributeMapping object
            attribute_filter_obj.seqDiagram = sequence_diagram_obj  # set the `seqDiagram` to `sequence_diagram_obj`
            attribute_filter_obj.save() # Now save the AttributeFilter object
            ...
            # redirect to success page on all all forms being valid

        ...    
        # render the page again with errors if any of the form is invalid
```

In our view, we check if all the forms are valid and then only save all the 3 objects into db. If any of the form is invalid, then we don't save any of them.
For the case when any of the form is invalid, you can add the code to render the page again with the form errors.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Although, I presume that I need `Formsets` since the data should be displayed in a table. Is there a way to match the two `Formsets` in the template so that an accurate table is displayed?